# Is there any way to disable share pass button from wallet pass and Android pay?

Tags: ios, iphone, android-pay, wallet

Is there any way to remove share pass button in wallet pass application of iOS 9.3 and afterwards? Whenever we scan a pass in wallet pass, there is always a button "share pass" through which if someone share the pass, all information including punches of pass will also be shared with pass. So I want to somehow disappear this share pass button from back of the pass. Is there any way to get rid of this button?
Same is the case in Android pass applications.
My application is in play 1.2.x framework.

Comment: The share pass button has been present since Wallet was released as Passbook in iOS6 and there is no way to disable it.  Because digital assets can easily be cloned (a screenshot is all it takes), It is up to the merchant to implement validity and authentication checks.

Comment: @PassKit, but if the pass uses NFC/fingerprint, there is no easy to clone it.  Would it make sense to allow non-shareable passes (esp. for those using NFC/fingerprint as authentication mean) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There is now**.

Include this key/value pair as a top-level key in `pass.json`

```
"sharingProhibited": true
```

*Sources*

As of 28 Dec 2017, Apple (in the Apple Wallet documentation's Revision History) says that it was revised to "[Describe] the sharingProhibited key", but no such description is anywhere to be found.

- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/RevisionHistory.html
- https://www.passsource.com/info/new.php

Comment: Also see: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/714/?time=2899